# Delta Table : org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: mismatched input 'FROM'

Tags: amazon-emr, delta-lake

I am trying to run the query on EMR/EMR Notebooks (Spark with Scala) -

```
SELECT max(version), max(timestamp) FROM (DESCRIBE HISTORY delta.`s3://a/b/c/d`)
```

But I am getting the following error -
[image]

The same query works fine on Databricks.

Another doubt that I have is - why does the colour of s3 location change post //.

[image]

So I tried to break the above query and only run the Describe HISTORY query. And for some reason it says -
[image]

Error Log -

```
An error was encountered:
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: HISTORY;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:47)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$lookupTableFromCatalog(Analyzer.scala:835)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.resolveRelation(Analyzer.scala:787)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:817)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:810)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:71)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:89)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:86)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:194)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.resolveOperatorsUp(AnalysisHelper.scala:86)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUp(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:810)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:756)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$2.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:92)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$2.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:92)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionMetrics$.withMetrics(QueryExecutionMetrics.scala:141)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:91)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:88)
  at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:88)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:80)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$executeSameContext(Analyzer.scala:164)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:156)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:156)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.AnalysisContext$.withLocalMetrics(Analyzer.scala:104)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:126)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:125)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:201)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:125)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:76)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:66)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.table(SparkSession.scala:630)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DescribeColumnCommand.run(tables.scala:714)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:79)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:196)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:196)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3391)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$SQLExecution$$executeQuery$1(SQLExecution.scala:83)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:94)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionMetrics$.withMetrics(QueryExecutionMetrics.scala:141)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$SQLExecution$$withMetrics(SQLExecution.scala:178)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:93)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:200)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:92)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withAction(Dataset.scala:3390)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:196)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:81)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:644)
  ... 50 elided
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchTableException: Table or view 'history' not found in database 'default';
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClient$$anonfun$getTable$1.apply(HiveClient.scala:81)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClient$$anonfun$getTable$1.apply(HiveClient.scala:81)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClient$class.getTable(HiveClient.scala:81)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.getTable(HiveClientImpl.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.getRawTable(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:141)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$getTable$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:723)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$getTable$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:723)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:98)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.getTable(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:722)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.ExternalCatalogWithListener.getTable(ExternalCatalogWithListener.scala:138)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.lookupRelation(SessionCatalog.scala:706)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$lookupTableFromCatalog(Analyzer.scala:832)
```

**UPDATED (18-Feb-2021) -> What I have tried till now.**

1. Query Using Spark Sql -

spark.sql("SELECT max(version), max(timestamp) FROM (DESCRIBE HISTORY delta.`s3://a/b/c/d`)")
But this Didnt work. Same Error.

2. Create Spark Session with  -

`spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension`
and `spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog`.

But its throwing the same error.
[image]

UPDATE 2 (18-Feb-2021) :- Trying the approach as mentioned by @alex.

Using PySpark.

It was working partly and but not completely.

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think DESCRIBE is something specific to Databricks based on what I know. Also try to see if it works inside spark.sql("")

Comment: Thanks @NikunjKakadiya, I did try it with Spark.sql("") but that didnt work either. Even I am inclined towards the fact that DESCRIBE HISTORY is a Databricks exclusive stuff but the official documentation in delta.io differs. Its becoming so confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Per [documentation](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-utility.html#retrieve-delta-table-history), to get support for `DESCRIBE HISTORY` you need to configure Spark SQL Extensions and Catalog by passing 2 properties (see [docs](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-utility.html#configure-sparksession)):

- `spark.sql.extensions` to value `io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension`
- `spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog` to value `org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog`

Update:

For Spark 2.4.x, the Delta 0.6.1 should be used, and its [documentation](https://docs.delta.io/0.6.1/delta-utility.html#-sql-support) has following code snippet to activate extensions:

```py
spark.sparkContext._jvm.io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension() \
        .apply(spark._jsparkSession.extensions())
spark = SparkSession(spark.sparkContext, spark._jsparkSession.cloneSession())
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex, I tried, but that didnt work either. I have updated my issue with your suggestion, can you check if there is anything else you want me to try out ? Thanks Again.

Comment: what Spark version is used?

Comment: I am on spark 2.4.7

Comment: Thanks @Alex, But I am using Scala, and even after following the documentation, and creating my sparkSession with the mentioned configs, it doesn't . I guess, the one you have mentioned is for PySpark right ? Do you want me to try that out ?

Comment: This registration piece is really problematic in Spark 2 - I was bitten by that in Cassandra connector...

Comment: Thanks a lot @Alex. I atleast got this working PARTIALLY on PySpark (Updated My Question) . I completely agree with you , this is so problematic , I am so much in love with Databricks now . :p Having said that, is there anything else I should try out to get over this issue ? It would be of great help to me. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: I think that you may need to go to Spark 3 and latest Delta

Comment: Cool, Let me try with Spark 3 too. I shall keep you posted. Thank you so much @alex

Comment: I upgraded to Spark 3 and all Delta functionalities work like charm . Thank you so much